# The vectors a and b are non-collinear. For what value(s) of m is it true that (m^2 + 2m - 3)a + (m^2 + m -6)b = 0?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Since they are both non-collinear they can never be equal to zero. So what do i do now?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: you might want to recheck your statement "Since they are both non-collinear they can never be equal to zero"... what do you have in your mind...

Comment: if you add non collinear vectors, it can never equal zero

Comment: it would be better if you write it in the question just to make it look better... :)

Comment: you might even want to make " $a,b$ are non zero vectors"....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik why doesnt the direction change when you multiply a vector by a positive scalar though?

Comment: direction changes when you multiply a vector by a negative scalar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Two vectors are non-collinear if and only if they are linearly independent (prove this!). Linear independence in this context means

$$c_1 a + c_2 b = 0 \iff c_1 = 0 = c_2$$

Comment: Should i factor both sets?

Comment: @T.Bongers : You are too fast.. :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The faster I go, the quicker I can procrastinate :)

Comment: @Jessica Yes, that's one way to solve for the values of $m$.

Comment: so how do i solve values for a and b?

Comment: given that i solved for m?

Comment: @Jessica $a$ and $b$ aren't numbers, and can't be solved for here. They're abstract vectors - the *only* salient piece of information is that they aren't collinear.

Comment: oh so a and b are unit vectors

Comment: so i would have 4 values for m and that is it?

Comment: @Jessica It's never given that $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors - they are *just* vectors. You won't have $4$ values of $m$, since it's necessary that $m^2 +2m - 3 = 0 = m^2 + m - 6$.

Comment: so m just equals -3 and thats the answer?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, that's it.

Comment: dont you need to consider cases?

Comment: rather m^2 + 2m - 3 = 0, where m = 1, -3

Comment: and m^2 + m - 6 = 0, where m= 2, -3

Comment: wait nvm the other values dont work! why not??

Comment: @T.Bongers ey who knows! Thank so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

You need both
$m^2+2m-3 = 0$
and
$m^2+m-6=0$.

Since
$m^2+2m-3
=(m+3)(m-1)
$,
the first equation is true
when
$m=-3$ or $m=1$.

Since
$m^2+m-6
=(m+3)(m-2)
$,
the second equation is true
when
$m=-3$ or $m=2$.

They two equations are both true
only when $m=-3$.